# Calculating image width when zoomed in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming

I'm working on a Winforms app that contains a large map image (5500px by 2500px).  I've set it up so the map starts in full size, but the user can zoom out to a few different scales to see more of the map.  The user is able to drag the map around to shift what they are looking at (like Google Maps, Bing Maps, Civilization, etc.).

When the map is full sized (scale = 1.0), I am able to prevent the user from scrolling past the borders of the image. I do this by calculating if they are trying to move past 0, or past the image width - current window size, similar to this:

```
if (_currHScroll <= 0) { 
    _currHScroll = 0;
}
```

This all works just fine.  But, when I zoom out on the map (thus, making the image smaller), the limits for the bottom and right of the map break down.  I know why this happens--because the Transform that is performed basically "compresses" the map a little bit, and so what used to be a 5000 px image is now smaller, depending on the scale. But, my limiters are based on the image size.

So, the user can scroll past the end of the map, and just sees white space.  Worse things happen, I realize, but if possible I'd like to keep them from doing that.

I'm sure there is a straight-forward way to do this, but I haven't figured it out yet.  I've tried simply multiplying my calculation by the scale, but that didn't seem to work (seems to under-estimate the size initially, then over-estimate on the smallest sizes).  I've tried calculating the transform location of the bottom right of the image, and using that, but it turns out, that number is inverted, and I can't find what it relates to.

I'm including my transform point method here.  It works just fine.  It tells me, regardless of zoom level, what pixel was clicked on the original image.  Thus, if someone clicks on point 200, 200 but the image is scaled at .5, it will show something like 400,400 as what was clicked (but, as I said, I don't think the scale value is a multiplier--using this just for demonstration purposes).

```
public Point GetTransformedPoint(Point mousePoint) {
    Matrix clickTransform = _mapTransform.Clone();
    Point[] xPoints = { new Point(mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y) };
    clickTransform.Invert();
    clickTransform.TransformPoints(xPoints);

    Debug.Print("Orig: {0}, {1} -- Trans: {2}, {3}", mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y, xPoints[0].X, xPoints[0].Y);

    return xPoints[0];
}
```

Many thanks in advance.  I'm sure it's something relatively easy that I'm overlooking, but after several hours, I'm just not finding it.

Comment: You already keep a Matrix around, also good to calculate the valid scroll range.  What you need to know to use it is completely unclear, your snippets don't have anything to do with scrolling.

Comment: It is not quite clear what kind of data you have at the moment. Are you using GDI+? Could you just get the new sizes of the image and use it as the new bounds?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, you can calculate the maximum with your method GetTransformedPoint by using width and height from your Image as Point. The result can then be used inside your check...

And by the way, you are right, the scale value is a multiplier used as a factor. The only thing is, you have to cast the result to an integer.

Comment: I appreciate the comment.  Unfortunately, I haven't gotten it to work, at least, not universally. I thought I had it solved at one point, but it only worked with a specific zoom level.  Other zoom levels failed.  I'm sure there's a relationship, I'm just not seeing it just yet.

Comment: Ok, so can you edit your question and provide the minimal but complete code, so we can look at it...